# Different input types (time, number) have varying height in chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I am trying to use input elements with different type attributes but having problems with varying height. In chrome input type:time looks higher than type:number for example. I have reduced it to the bare bones to illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4jteqy1f/

HTML

```
<article class="settings">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="time" value="00:00">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="time" value="00:00">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="number" value="286">
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

CSS

```
.settings ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    background-color: #dee7f8;
}
```

In the example the input of type number looks smaller that the rest of input fields at least in chrome. It looks fine in latest Internet explorer for a change. Why is this happening and what are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line to your CSS:

```
input{padding: 0 0 0 3px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;}
```

The basic idea is to provide enough room for the up and down buttons, which is 20px, then the `vertical-align: middle` to affect the values (it won't affect the DOM elements like the arrows, though)

see the code and play around with sizes so you understand how it works

```css
.settings div li{
 display: inline-block;
    padding:5px;
 background-color: #dee7f8;
}
input{padding: 0 0 0 3px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<article class="settings">
    <div>
        <li>
            <input type="time" value="00:00">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="time" value="00:00">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input value="286">
        </li>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: It does seem to work but it is ugly. I still don't really understand why left padding fixes the issue and why it only affects some input types. Both types have up/down buttons so it should be 20px by default for both types... Can you add why this happens in the first place in chrome?

Comment: you have misread my explanation. The padding has been added only for some spacing to it doesn't collide with the border, the 20px is for HEIGHT, and that height is 10px for each of the up and down arrows

Comment: That's what I thought but if I remove padding the element becomes slightly larger than the others. What I don't get is why you need 20px for one type of element but not the other, I mean they both have the same size arrows.